# Unable to use `run` routine on complex bash command

Tags: raku

Got this command: `cd /some/dir; /usr/local/bin/git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aI -- /some/dir/file  | tail -1`

I want to get the output from it.

Tried this:

`my $proc2 = run 'cd', $dirname, ';', '/usr/local/bin/git', 'log', '--diff-filter=A', '--follow', '--format=%aI', '--', $output_file, '|', 'tail', '-1', :out, :err;`

Nothing output.

Tried this:

`my $proc2 = run </usr/local/bin/git -C>, $dirname, <log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aI -->, $output_file,  <| tail -1>, :out, :err;`

Git throws an error:

`fatal: --follow requires exactly one pathspec`

The same git command runs fine when run directly from the command line.

I've confirmed both `$dirname` and `$output_file` are correct.

`git log --help` didn't shed any light on this for me. Command runs fine straight from command line.

**UPDATE:** So if I take off the `| tail -1` bit, I get output from the command in raku (a date). I also discovered if I take the pipe out when running on the command line, the output gets piped into `more`. I'm not knowledgeable enough about bash and how it might interact with raku's `run` command to know for sure what's going on.

Comment: `;` is not really a command; run puts single commands with all their options. Also, you can just change directory using [chdir](https://docs.raku.org/routine/chdir)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to run a separate proc for piping:

```raku
my $p = run «git -C "$dirname" log --diff-filter=A --format=%aI», :out, :err; 
my $p2 = run <tail -1>, :in($p.out), :out;
put .out.slurp: :close with $p2;
```

Also you don't need tail in this case, you can do:

```raku
put .out.lines(:close).tail with $p
```